# jQuery list, styling <li> fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to do a listing with `li` elements and when I click on one of those `<li>` s then change the background of the `li` element and if I click on another than change the other `li`'s background and return the other `li`'s background to the original color.

Something like this:

```
<ul>
 <li>Option1</li>
 <li>Option2</li>
</ul>
```

and when I click on option 1 highlight its background or put a border, and wen I click on option 2 then return the first divs propietes and change the option 2's background color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
$("li").click(function(){
  $("li").css("backgroundColor", "white");
  $(this).css("backgroundColor", "yellow");
});
```

});

Working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XzdFf/)

Answer (score 0):

Initialize a var representing the currently selected li on page load (none selected). Add a click event to each li that calls a highlight update method with itself as a parameter. The method should disable the highlight on the currently selected li, enable it on the clicked one, and set the currently selected one to be the clicked one. Hope that's clear!

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood what you're looking for correctly, something like this should work:

```
$("li").click(function() {
    $("li").css("backgroundColor", "#ff0000");
    $(this).css("backgroundColor", "#000000");
});
```

This attaches a `click` event listener to all `li` elements. When one is clicked, it sets the background of all of them, then changes the background of the clicked one.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>hello</li>
    <li>hello</li>  
</ul>
```

**Javascript**

```
$("li").click(function () {
    $(this).css("background-color","red");
    $(this).siblings().css("background-color","white");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ipr101/kKZhN/

Answer (score 0):

You can use radio options for this as well. 
Javascript (Jquery approach)

```
$("#radio").buttonset();
```

HTML

```
<div id="radio" class='demo'>
    <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio" /><label for="radio1">label 1</label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radio" /><label for="radio2">label 2</label>
</div>
```

Comment: I realize this is not **"Exactly"** what you asked for, however it is a very felxible approach.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to do highlight for each row when they are clicked? You could apply a class when the li is clicked and remove the class from all other li before adding it.

```
$('ul li').click(function(){
  $(this).siblings().removeClass('classname'); 
  $(this).toggleClass('classname');  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid at inline styling as much as you can. Instead create a pseudo-class in your css.

css:

```
li {
background:#fff;
}
li.selected {
background:#eee;
}
```

js:

```
$('li').click(function(){
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
```